# Questions example phoneNumber

Tags: javascript

I am a student studying JavaScript.
It hasn't been long since I studied.
Example, createPhoneNumber
The length is up to 11 digits.
I wrote the code in question like this.

```
function createPhoneNumber(arr) {
    let first = '(010)';
      if(arr.length === 11){
       return `(${arr.slice(0,3).join('')})${arr.slice(3,7).join('')}-${arr.slice(7,11).join('')}`;
     }
     return `${first}${arr.slice(0,4).join('')}-${arr.slice(4,8).join('')}`;
     }
```

I think it's very messy code.

Is it better to add a new variable to make it shorter and simpler?

Comment: What do you want as output from this function?

Comment: Instead of slicing the array, you could try looping through it with a `for`-loop and add the seperators using the [`modulo operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Modulo).

Comment: @wgumenyuk how is that in any way easier? It would lead to a *more complex* code.

Comment: @VLAZ While it would indeed make the code more complex, I believe it's a cleaner approach instead of manually slicing the array into small parts.

Comment: @wgumenyuk disagree. You would now have to maintain all possible separators for all possible formats and you'll have a mess of `if/else` statements all over the code. Adding a third format will mean it's no longer possible to understand WHAT the formats look like. Adding a fourth one would be a nightmare. Given that the formats are *extremely* simple, there is no need to make the code harder to read, write, and maintain. These are three actions you want to be *easy*. If there is a huge amount of formats to maintain, a regex replacement is the easiest way to handle all of them.

Comment: @VLAZ I see your point. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna I simply want to know the different ways of code in createPhoneNumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by `Regex`:

```js
function createPhoneNumber(arr) {
   let first = '(010)';
   // the submatch (\D)? is intended to get an empty match when the length of arr is not 11
   let reg = arr.length == 11 ? /(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})/ : /(\D)?(\d{4})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,})/;
   return arr.join('').replace(reg, (match, $1, $2, $3) => ($1 ? "(" + $1 + ")" : first) + $2 + "-" + $3);
}

console.log(createPhoneNumber([0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
console.log(createPhoneNumber([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
console.log(createPhoneNumber([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want it shorter and simpler? This is subjective but I believe the following applies. Also, I wasn't sure if you misused your 11th digit in your function so... I made it work with 10.

```
function createPhoneNumber(arr) {
  const arrL = arr.length;
  let arrI = arrL - 4;
  arr.splice(arrI, 0, "-");
  arr.splice(arrI -= 3, 0, ")");
  arr.splice(0, 0, arrL === 10 ? "(" : "(010");
  return arr.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of readability, I suggest a few changes:

1. Export hard coded values to `const`.
2. Don't duplicate your code! like the complicated `return` you had.
3. It did look messy - do I decided to separate the number to 3 parts - 3 variables, and use 1 `return`

```js
const PRE_FIRST = '(010)';
const FULL_NUMBER_LENGTH = 11;

function createPhoneNumber(arr) {
  let isFullPhone = FULL_NUMBER_LENGTH === arr.length;
  let first = isFullPhone ? arr.slice(0, 3).join('') : PRE_FIRST;
  let second = (isFullPhone ? arr.slice(3, 7) : arr.slice(0, 4)).join('');
  let third = (isFullPhone ? arr.slice(7, 11) : arr.slice(4, 8)).join('');
  return `${first}-${second}-${third}`;
}
```